# Expected value of E(|X-Y|) for X and Y uniformly distributed between 0 and 1

Tags: expected-value

Anyone has an answer for this? I did the math and I think the answer is 1/3, but I'm not sure and would like validation.

Comment: This question is the special case of $N=2$ in the duplicate.  It's also a limiting case of the question answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52909 where one side of the rectangle approaches zero and the other has unit length.

Comment: Ohh, how dumb of me, I hadn't thought about simulating it to verify my answer... It is 1/3, nice!

Comment: If you have the skills to create simple simulations, they open up a wonderful resource for checking your solutions to probability questions.  I use simulations all the time to check that I haven't made some huge error in any analyses I post here ;-).  Sometimes, just thinking about how to simulate a situation leads to an analytical solution, too.