# What is an intuitive explanation for why my mean absolute error converges to 66.6%?

Tags: mae

Let's assume I have actual numbers (randomly generated) between 1 and 1000. Let's further assume, my prediction model tries to predict the actual numbers. My "forecasting" model is a monkey that true-randomly presses buttons between 1 and 1000. Essentially, it is the same function which is used to generate the actual numbers. I just put two sets of randomly generated numbers next to each other and calculate their difference ("error").

If I follow this logic and calculate the mean absolute error of the monkey model and normalize it with the actual numbers, the MAE will be around 66%. Just to confirm, the formula to calculate the MAE is: SUM(ABS(Actual-Forecast))/SUM(Actual).

You can create this model easily in Excel.

What is an intuitive explanation for why I get exactly a value of 66.666% the more numbers I generate? My understanding is, that on average I predict 66% of an actual figure wrong.

Comment: The MAE would be the average of ABS(Actual-Forecast). Instead of averaging, you take the sum and divide by the sum of the actuals. This is a kind of a weighted MAPE ([Kolassa & Schütz, 2007](https://econpapers.repec.org/article/forijafaa/y_3a2007_3ai_3a6_3ap_3a40-43.htm)).

Comment: i used the german wikipedia article for the formula of the mean absolute error calculation and the first normalization shown in the wiki article is basically what i am doing. in the article the MAE is divided by the average actual value. It is essentially the same like dividing the sum of abs errors with the sum of actuals.

Comment: Well, that is a *normalized* MAE, not the MAE, there is a difference.

Comment: you are right, maybe i should have mentioned that in the title. In my explanation I mentioned that I normalize the MAE with the actual numbers.

Comment: This is answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52909 for the two-dimensional analog -- which reduces to this question for an arbitrarily skinny rectangle.

Comment: Why not assume nothing, go back and list what you actually know?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can consider this as randomly drawing a number on a square and computing the vertical distance to the diagonal.

[image: example of computing vertical distance]

Then this relates to the average of the [triangular distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution).

If we fill in the formula for the mean of that distribution, with $a = c = 0$ and $b=1$, then you get $MAE = \frac{1}{3}$ and your division with the actual value $\frac{1}{2}$ makes it a relative error of $\frac{2}{3}$.

---

Alternative viewpoint, you can also consider the perpendicular distance to the diagonal which is the residual vector in estimating the mean $(x-\mu, y-\mu)$, where $\mu = \frac{x+y}{2}$.

[image: diagonal projection]

Another alternative viewpoint, consider that the plot of $(x-y)$ and $(x+y)$, two values that you use in your computation, is a rotation, shift and scaling of the square.

[image: rotated]

Comment: Why can we "*consider this as randomly drawing a number on a square and computing the distance to the diagonal*"? To me, it's more like "randomly drawing two points from a square and computing the distance between them".

Comment: @Zhanxiong It's like the transformation to coordinates $x-y$ and $x+y$ which scales, rotates and shifts the square. It gives a geometric interpretation to why $|x-y|$ resembles a triangular distribution.

Comment: @Zhanxiong if you take your approach, then it is like randomly drawing two points on a line (instead of a square). You can do it like that and compute the integral, but it gives less of a  geometrical intuition how you get this triangle.

Comment: Alternatively to my representation, you can also consider the projection straight down to the diagonal.

Comment: I posted, IMHO, a more straightforward (in that there is no "discrete-to-continuous" or projection transformations) proof.

Comment: @Zhanxiong yes, it is also easily proven by working out a sum/integral for discrete/continuous cases. $$\frac{\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{x=1}^n \sum_{y=1}^n |x-y|}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{x=1}^n x} = \dots =  \frac{2}{3}$$ I did the indirect less straightforward approach on purpose, to make the algebraic steps more intuitive. It's like deriving $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k = k(k+1)/2$ which can be done with a geometric approach (like imagining a square of $k$ by $k+1$ and splitting it into two triangles).

Comment: Also, I didn't expect this post to get so popular. It's simple and I didn't create a full complete treatment. See my [first version of the answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/revisions/642899/1) which was just a pen and paper solution and a hint that it relates to a triangle distribution.

Comment: Correction $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k = n(n+1)/2$

Comment: The distance to the diagonal is the error divided by $\sqrt 2$, isn't it? If the pair is $(0, 1)$, then the error is $1$ but the distance to the diagonal is $\sqrt 2 / 2$.

Comment: @TannerSwett The diagonal distance has indeed a factor $\sqrt{2}$. I regarded only the difference in the horizontal component. I have changed it now into a different viewpoint that avoids the potential confusion (although the diagonal projection to the diagonal line has some nice aspect as it occurs in other problems; it is namely the residual vector of a computation of the mean; example: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/365070/)

Answer (score 7):

Below is how I interpreted and confirmed your empirical study.

The experiment can be described as follows:

1. Draw two independent random variables $X$ (representing "actual") and $Y$ (representing "monkey prediction") from the uniform discrete distribution $\{1, 2, \ldots, c\}$.  In your case $c = 1000$.
2. Repeat this for $n$ times.  So you will collect data $\{(X_1, Y_1), 
   (X_2, Y_2), \ldots, (X_n, Y_n)\}$.

Your conjecture is that
\begin{align*}
MAE_n = \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n|X_i - Y_i|}{\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i} \to \frac{2}{3}
\end{align*}
as $n \to \infty$ (in some convergence mode). I will show that $MAE_n \to 2/3$ with probability $1$.

To this end, by SLLN, with probability $1$:
\begin{align*}
& \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n|X_i - Y_i| \to E[|X - Y|], \\
& \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i \to E[X]. \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align*}

It thus suffices to evaluate $E[X]$ and $E[|X - Y|]$ respectively, which are:
\begin{align*}
& E[X] = c^{-1}\sum_{k = 1}^c k = \frac{1 + c}{2}, \\
& E[|X - Y|] = c^{-2}\sum_{k = 1}^c \sum_{l = 1}^c |k - l| = \frac{c^2 - 1}{3c}. \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align*}

It then follows by $\eqref{1}$ and $\eqref{2}$ that
\begin{align*}
MAE_n \to \frac{\frac{c^2 - 1}{3c}}{\frac{1 + c}{2}} = \frac{2}{3}\times\frac{c - 1}{c} \text{ with probability } 1.
\end{align*}
Hence when $c = 1000$, the limit is of course very close to $\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: Very nice. The only thing is that it's more MAPE than MAE, if you take error proportional to the actual.